# How to embed d3js/html widgets figure in r markdown html output

Tags: r

I came across a beautiful R code of d3_exploding_boxplot in htmlwidget form for R (https://github.com/timelyportfolio/explodingboxplotR)  ----the boxplots dissolves into scatter plot if we click on the boxplot----very cool indeed

Code:

```
Installation

# get newest htmlwidgets
devtools::install_github("ramnathv/htmlwidgets")
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/explodingboxplotR")

Usage

library(explodingboxplotR)

# use this to replicate
#   from ?boxplot
#boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")

exploding_boxplot(
data.frame(
rowname = rownames(InsectSprays),
InsectSprays,
stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
y = "count",
group = "spray",
color = "spray",
label = "rowname"
)
```

The problem is that after running the code we get the interactive boxplot in R studio graph viewer pane but when u knit it into r markdown html document, the graph is not visible at all.....It simply means i have to somehow render the html widget and embed into the html document which i dont know how to do it....have googled for solution but alas.....

Comment: The exploding boxplots are rendering correctly for me when I put them into a RMarkdown presentation and knit.  Can you possibly post a reproducible RMarkdown document where it is not working?

Comment: Do you have the newest versions of `htmlwidgets` and `rmarkdown`?  These are evolving quite rapidly so my guess would be outdated packages.  As Matt suggested, if you can post your `rmarkdown` code or the erroneous result, I'm sure we can help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a vignette to the package to demonstrate how to use `explodingboxplotR` in a `rmarkdown` document.  The code looks like this.

````
---
title: "Intro to Exploding Boxplots"
author: "Kenton Russell"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Intro to Exploding Boxplots}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

[Exploding Boxplots](https://github.com/mcaule/d3_exploding_boxplot) provide a fun and useful look at the distribution of data.  This `R` package [`explodingboxplotR`](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/explodingboxplotR) uses `htmlwidgets` to allow us to incorporate these exploding boxplots in all R contexts, such as `rmarkdown`, `Shiny`, the `R` console, and in a web browser.

### Install

`explodingboxplotR` is not on CRAN, so we'll use `devtools::install_github` to install.

```{r eval = FALSE}
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/explodingboxplotR")
```

### Use

```{r}
library(explodingboxplotR)

# use this to replicate
#   from ?boxplot
#boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")

exploding_boxplot(
  data.frame(
    rowname = rownames(InsectSprays),
    InsectSprays,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ),
  y = "count",
  group = "spray",
  color = "spray",
  label = "rowname"
)
```

We get some options to customize our exploding boxplots.  Let's look at these in the next example.

```{r}
# demonstrate all of the options
#  xlab does not work
#  filed issue on source repo
exploding_boxplot(
  data.frame(
    rowname = rownames(InsectSprays),
    InsectSprays,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ),
  y = "count",
  group = "spray",
  color = "spray",
  label = "rowname",
  iqr = 2,
  margin = list(bottom = 50, left = 30, top = 20, right = 20),
  xlab = "Spray Type",
  ylab = "Count Provided"
)
```
````

`devtools::session_info()` for this working version

```
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.875)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Chicago             
 date     2016-02-03                  

Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version     date       source                              
 devtools      1.9.1.9000  2015-10-24 local                               
 digest        0.6.9       2016-01-08 CRAN (R 3.2.3)                      
 DT            0.0.20      2015-03-12 Github (rstudio/DT@e7130f7)         
 htmltools     0.3         2015-12-29 CRAN (R 3.2.3)                      
 htmlwidgets   0.5.2       2016-01-29 local                               
 httpuv        1.3.3       2015-08-04 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                      
 jsonlite      0.9.19.9000 2015-12-01 Github (jeroenooms/jsonlite@2158a16)
 knitr         1.11        2015-08-14 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                      
 magrittr      1.5         2015-04-17 Github (smbache/magrittr@89f143d)   
 memoise       0.2.1       2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.1.0)                      
 mime          0.4         2015-09-03 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                      
 R6            2.1.1       2015-08-19 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                      
 Rcpp          0.12.3      2016-01-10 CRAN (R 3.2.3)                      
 rmarkdown     0.9.2       2016-01-01 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                      
 shiny       * 0.12.2      2015-08-05 CRAN (R 3.2.3)                      
 xtable        1.7-4       2014-09-12 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                      
 yaml          2.1.13      2014-06-12 CRAN (R 3.1.3)
```